# ng repeat not updating

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi I am a newbie to angular js and I am hoping someone can help me out with the following problem.

I have a numeric field called numAdults and I need to show a set of field (such as name, address, telephone etc ) numAdult times to get those information for each of those person.

Here is the jsfiddle for the problem [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/bRgTR/3/)

Here is also an overview of code of the controller

```
function bookingController($scope){
$scope.numAdults = 1;
$scope.personLoop = function(){
    console.log('personLoop called')
    return new Array($scope.numAdults);
    //return new Array(2);
    
}
```

the html

```
<label for="book_num_adults">Number of adults:</label>
<input id="book_num_adults" type="text" ng-model="numAdults">


  <div class="row" ng-repeat="t in personLoop()" style="border:2px solid red;margin-top:10px">
      <h4>Person {{$index+1}}</h4>
       <input placeholder="name"><br>
       <input placeholder="address"><br>
       <input placeholder="telephone"><br>
  </div>
```

Can you also help me with how to transform this as an module ( not just a controller based )

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your Fiddle was riddled with errors...

http://jsfiddle.net/bRgTR/5/

1. Under Frameworks & Extensions, you need to change the 2nd dropdown from "onLoad" to one of the "No wrap" options
2. Your `controller` definition is mangled.  It's supposed to be: `.controller('name', ['depname', function (depname) { })]);` -- you had your closing array misplaced.
3. You should really use semi-colons.
4. You don't create an array of 5 items in JavaScript like this: `var a = new Array(5)`, that creates an array that contains a 5.  Instead, you should do `var a = []; a.length = 5;`

Comment: Ah, then #4 should answer your question.

Comment: Oh great! and thank you. I wasn't actually able to properly modularize this, can you help me?

Comment: What do you mean by properly modularize?  My fiddle link at the top uses `angular.module`, which I assume is what you mean.